# TrueCrypt and Windows backup, what works and what doesn't?

Tags: windows-vista, backup, truecrypt, windows-backup

On the Truecrypt docs->limitations section it states that

> The Windows Volume Shadow Copy Service is currently supported only for partitions within the key scope of active system encryption (e.g. a system partition encrypted by TrueCrypt, or a non-system partition located on a system drive encrypted by TrueCrypt, mounted when the encrypted operating system is running). Note: For other types of volumes, the Volume Shadow Copy Service is not supported because the documentation for the necessary API is not available.

What does the "key scope" of active system encryption actually mean?
Are the examples listed above of what should work meant to be exhaustive, or are there other posibilities?

I certainly have not been able to get the Vista file-backup utility to give me the option to backup files that reside ANYWHERE other than the encrypted system partition and any unencripted (non TrueCrypt) mounted partitions.

I have tried to see if the Vista file-backup tool recognises the following TrueCrypt mounted partitions as candidates for backup but it doesn't

- Non System TC NTFS partition (I thought this would work as per the TC docs quoted above?)
- TC NTFS File container (ok not in the doc blurb so maybe this shouldn't work...)

I am working from a non Hidden OS partition (to keep things simple, althougth I can't get it to work from a Hidden OS partition either...)

What might I be doing wrong?
Anybody got automatic backup working from TC volumes using Vista backup tools?
perhaps using some other backup tool (a TC aware tool would be nice)

Thanks